# Dropdown option menu only work once

Tags: jquery, dropdown, html-select

I have a dropdown option and inside a form. But after i submit the form the dropdown option stop working.

```
  <form role="form" method="post" action="" >                    
<div class="form-group" style="padding:12px;">
  <textarea class="form-control animated" placeholder="Update your status" name="text"></textarea>
  <script>
      $(function(){
      $('.normal').autosize();
      $('.animated').autosize({append: "\n"});
    });
  </script>
  <div class="row" >
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <label for="select-custom-17">Subject</label>
        <select name="subject" id="select-custom-17" data-native-menu="false">
        <option value="BIT304">BIT304</option>
        <option value="BIT305">BIT305</option>
        <option value="BIT215">BIT215</option>
        <option value="BIT102">BIT102</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <input type="submit" value="SHARE"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

i found out that when i remove the

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

in the head of the file, the dropdown option works fine.
Is it the problem of the js script or did i miss anything?

Comment: are you using another javascript. this may be jquery conflict issue

Comment: can you post JS Fiddle or something like that, where we can test your code?

Comment: Have you checked your scripts order. I mean jquery library first after that auto size library.

Answer (score 0):

Mention "name"  to your button if you are using php or give proper id to your button if you are using  ajx jQuery

Answer (score 0):

I think that is jquery conflict issue, maybe u are using another jquery plugin so it was happen.

Comment: i was using jquery mobile also and jquery

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine, see the demo [https://jsfiddle.net/m1c23ywb/](https://jsfiddle.net/m1c23ywb/)

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code in the online [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/ujwnedmL/). It worked fine.

May be, you were missing something that might have prevented the `dropdown` from working.